# status of the process in powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, process, state, status

A process in windows can be in any of the six states i.e, running, ready, blocked, suspend, new and exit. How to know the state a given process (name, ID) using powershell in windows.
In UNIX this information is stored in /proc/$processid/status file. Where is it found in windows or how to get this information in powershell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"exit" status is signified by the presense of "exit code" property (natively returned by [`GetExitCodeProcess()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683189%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). In PS, it is reflected by `HasExited` and `ExitCode` fields in `Get-Process` (alias `ps`).

```
ps | where {$_.Id -eq <PID>} | select HasExited,ExitCode
```

"running/wait/suspended" in Windows is a [status of a thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.threadstate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) rather than process ("suspend" being one of several [Wait substates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tkhtkxxy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)). I didn't find any info on getting thread information by PS's built-in means but we can [call the corresponding .NET functionality](http://sreerenjnair.wordpress.com/2012/01/20/how-to-call-a-net-method-in-powershell-2-0/):

```
$process=[System.Diagnostics.Process]::GetProcessById(<PID>)
$threads=$process.Threads
$threads | select Id,ThreadState,WaitReason
```

Answer (score 1):

You are right, that's an interesting point. A way to find out about the state the process is the following way :

```
$ProcessActive = Get-Process outlook -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if($ProcessActive -eq $null)
{
 Write-host "I am not running"
}
else
{
 Write-host "I am running"
}
```

If outlook would not be a running process, it would not be listed but -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue will simply continue and return an `I am not running`

If it's running it will send you an `I am running`

I am not aware of other states of a process... at least not how to dertermine

Comment: What if you want to return the `Write-host` part?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this cmdlet to get all available info of a process:

`Get-Process -Name <process name> | Format-List *`

then you can try this cmdlet to see the state of that process, if it's True means it's running, if false means it's not running

`Get-Process -Name <process name> | select Responding`